# Is there a maintenance script that can change all links on pages after a changing the name of a namespace?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki

Currently, we have about 100 pages under a certain namespace, let's say 'Foo:'. Much more pages contain references to such pages, like so: [[Foo:Hello|Hello]]. If we change the namespace from 'Foo:' to 'Foo2:', all links like [[Foo:Hello|Hello]] are broken because they should now be [[Foo2:Hello|Hello]].

Before I manually search for all such broken links, is there a maintenance script that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

[Extension:Replace Text](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text) will do that

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set `$wgNamespaceAliases['Old namespace name'] = NS_WHATEVER_NAMESPACE`?